# get text value from text box using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table being drilled out with PHP in a recorders. I am using the table to update pricing. I have a text input and a form button. The button fires an Ajax call and updates the table. Right now I have the jQuery script inside the repeat region, but sometimes I have over 500 records.. Right now I use btn_2345 where 2345 is the unique I'd and the script fire on click btn_2345. How can I just use the script outside the repeat only once and get the values of the input text box and unique id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a table like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><button>go</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><button>go</button></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- ... -->
</table>
```

Then you could add a `data-id` attribute to the rows, walk up the DOM from your `<button>` to the `<tr>` to get the ID, then go back down the DOM to find the `<input>`. The HTML would be sort of like this:

```
<table>
    <tr data-id="11">
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><button>go</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="23">
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><button>go</button></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- ... -->
</table>
```

And the JavaScript sort of like this:

```
$('table button').click(function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var id  = $tr.data('id');
    var val = $tr.find('input[type=text]').val();
    // ...
});
```

You could also put the click handler in a named function if you like.

You could make it even nicer by attaching a class to the `<tr>` elements and using that class with `closest`:

```
<table>
    <tr data-id="11" class="one-chunk">
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <!--...-->
```

and

```
$('table button').click(function() {
    var $chunk = $(this).closest('one-chunk');
    var id     = $chunk.data('id');
    var val    = $chunk.find('input[type=text]').val();
    //...
});
```

Comment: Interesting use of HTML5 data attributes.

Comment: @Yzmir: I use that style a lot, it makes the per-chunk templates nice and simple and the jQuery is only loosely bound to the HTML structure. Adding a class to the `<tr>` and using `$(this).closest('.some-class')` would be even better.

Comment: great thank you. Looks like exactly what I need.  If I need to pass a couple hidden variables with it, how can I do that. I see you are using $re

Comment: $tr.find instead of an I'd or class attribute.

Comment: @Greg: You could add some `<input type="hidden">` elements and look them up by name or you could add more `data-X` attributes to the `<tr>` to hold them.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use

```
<input type="submit" class="my-button" id="2345">
```

then you can use class as selector in jquery, and use id as the value you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you generate HTML for many rows, where each row has a button associated with it, why not just generate with `onClick` and a `rowId` that is available on each iteration:

```
onClick="javascript: edit( rowId );"
```

So the generated result would look something like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><button onclick="javascript: edit( '2345' );">edit</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><button onclick="javascript: edit( '2346' );">edit</button></td>
    </tr>
    ....
</table>
```

Where you would not need to guess the ID.